# How do I generate 100 variance-covariance matrices using R from rnorm

Tags: r

Im a novice in R. I want to simulate 100 variance-covariance matrices from a multivariate normal random variables. How do I go about it

Comment: Hi Usman, this might be of use to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59277529/variance-covariance-matrix-in-r

Answer (score 0):

For one variance-covariance matrix based on 100 replicates and 3 variables:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(42)
mu <- rep(0, 3)
Sigma <- matrix(c(1, .5, .5, .5, 1, .25, .5, .25, 1), 3, 3)
dat <- var(mvrnorm(100, mu, Sigma))
print(dat, digits=3)
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
# [1,] 0.942 0.498 0.568
# [2,] 0.498 1.042 0.432
# [3,] 0.568 0.432 1.049
```

For a list of 10 matrices:

```
dat10 <- replicate(10, var(mvrnorm(100, mu, Sigma)), simplify=FALSE)
print(dat10[[1]], digits=3)
# print(dat10[[1]], digits=3)
#       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]
# [1,] 0.910 0.2015 0.4771
# [2,] 0.202 0.7826 0.0926
# [3,] 0.477 0.0926 0.9632
```